# Truncate chars with a read more link that when clicked honors the paragraph tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, truncate

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbAzW/79/).

You will notice one div tag with two paragraph tags in it. I'd like the read more to work as it is currently but when you click the read more link it shows the text with the html. Currently it seems to strip the `<p>` tags but I need them to stay.

```
    var shortenP = function(options) {

        options = $.extend({
        length: 160,
        ellipsis: ' [...]',
        moreClass: 'more-link',
        moreText: 'Read More'
    }, options);

    $('div').each(function() {

        var $p = $(this);
        var text = $p.text();
        var shortString = text.substring(0, options.length) + options.ellipsis;
        $p.data('fulltext', text);
        $p.text(shortString);
        $('<a/>').attr({
            href: '#',
            'class': options.moreClass
        }).text(options.moreText).
        insertAfter($p);
        $p.next().click(function(e) {

        $p.text($p.data('fulltext'));
        e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

    };

    shortenP();

    <div>
        <p>Rhoncus dolor porta pellentesque nec arcu! Tincidunt porttitor! Proin magnis elit diam       penatibus lundium, integer et, mauris a! Augue porta. Nec integer placerat integer? Ut aliquet montes lorem, duis nascetur! Facilisis risus magnis in aliquam non, eros elementum augue pid! Etiam adipiscing lacus parturient aliquam ultricies tortor lectus sagittis turpis diam, pulvinar. Rhoncus vel!</p>

        <p>Scelerisque porttitor ac tristique cum! Magnis porta rhoncus cum augue amet, in nec, magna! Odio? Integer in. Nec pulvinar, ac cursus est, enim? Placerat lundium! Egestas vel mus tempor, ultrices auctor, magnis mauris? Adipiscing habitasse est enim massa et! Hac in odio scelerisque. Duis turpis nisi, mauris, natoque, tortor, dis?</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you meant like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/udsxpLfq/)

Just adjusted to keep the paragraph-tags with an additional function to unescape the html and fetching the html instead of the text.

```
var shortenP = function(options) {

options = $.extend({
    length: 160,
    ellipsis: ' [...]',
    moreClass: 'more-link',
    moreText: 'Read More'
}, options);

$('div').each(function() {

    var $p = $(this);
    var text = $p.html();
    var shortString = text.substring(0, options.length) + options.ellipsis;
    $p.data('fulltext', text);
    $p.html(unescapeHtml(shortString));
    $('<a/>').attr({
        href: '#',
        'class': options.moreClass
    }).html(options.moreText).
    insertAfter($p);
    $p.next().click(function(e) {

        $p.html($p.data('fulltext'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

};

shortenP();
function unescapeHtml(text) {
return text.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
    .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
    .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}
```

Comment: @Noctane Glad to be of help, wasn't sure if it was that what you wanted as result.

Comment: That was it thank you. I tried to mark your answer as the answer but it wont let me for whatever reason.

Comment: @Noctane Thanks for letting me know, but the answer _is_ already marked/accepted - I've just checked the reputation history, and you accepted it on Sep 18th, so everything is ok.